# Restore single app from Google backup

Tags: backup, restore, app-data

I have two devices that both have automatic backups enabled through settings. I see both backups on Google drive.

The settings have an "auto restore" option, which implies there's most be a non-auto way to restore, but I can't find it. (Not that I managed to decipher how auto restore works).

So how can I restore the app data from it's backup, and,
Can I restore the app of 1 device to the backup of the other?

Comment: No. Unless it has changed with Oreo, those Google backups are nothing a user can control (apart from the "use it y/n" button in setup). Backup is controlled by the apps supporting it, and restore happens only (if at all) after a factory-reset on initial setup – and even then often enough fails completely or remains incomplete.